# Validate date month and year

Tags: php

I have a date in the form MM-YYYY (e.g: `04-2000`). I exploded the date into month and year and am now trying to check certain conditions on the month:

- between 1 and 12
- formed of 2 digits)

and on the year:

- formed of 4 digits

Is my syntax correct?

```
list($name_month, $name_year) = explode('-', $name_date, 2);
if(($name_month < 1 || $name_month > 12 || $name_month ) || ($name_year)) {
    echo "<br><br>Wrong date";
    $uploadOk = 0;}
```

Comment: Are you trying to validate a date?

Comment: See answer from @George below. There are a few gotchas in date validation but there are hundreds of answers on the subject

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the DateTime object and [`createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) to validate your date:

```
$date = '04-2000';

// Create a DateTime object pointing to the 1st of your given month and year
$d = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', '01-' . $date);
if($d && $d->format('m-Y') == $date){
  echo 'Valid date';
}
```

[**Eval.in**](https://eval.in/400606)

Comment: the value in date is not always the same.

list($name_loc, $name_date) = explode('-', $file_name, 2);
if($name_loc != "Cal") {
    echo "<br><br>Wrong file name";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
list($name_month, $name_year) = explode('-', $name_date, 2);
if(($name_month < 1 || $name_month > 12 || $name_month ) || ($name_year)) {
    echo "<br><br>Wrong date";
    $uploadOk = 0;}

Comment: Sleek, but note that it will also validate two digit years format like `02-02` will also produce `Valid date`.

Comment: @Viral so how can i validate a 4 digit year only

Comment: - **This answer is incorrect**, fails with `$date = '02-2015'` when current day is after the 28th... Don't use this at home kids!

Answer (score 1):

This should work, if seprator is always `-`

```
$date = '04-2000';

if($date == date('m-Y', strtotime('01-'.$date)))
{
    echo 'Valid date';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As commented, there are several was to do this. What first comes to mind is [`checkdate()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php) and [`createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php).

The catch is, you need to be mindful what is injected for the day part since your format does not include day.

Since `createFromFormat()` injects the day part from the current date, it is not a viable option. **George**'s code will fail for a format of `02-2015` on days after 28.

As such, I would use `checkdate()`:

```
$date = '04-2000';
list($month, $year) = explode('-', $date);
if (checkdate($month, 1, $year)) {
  echo 'Valid date';
}
```